# load data from MongoDB into HDFS and hbase

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig

we have 5 tera bytes of mongodb data and our client wants to move to and process data with Hadoop.

Our requirement is to load data from MongoDB into HDFS and process it and store into another random access DB.

Our(team) thought is to load data from mongoDB to HDFS using mongo-hadoop driver and process it with HIVE and load data into HBASE for random accessing.

So, is there any other better way to do this. Please provide your suggestions.

FYI: We have 20 node cluster.

Comment: I am curious if we can load MongoDB data using mongo-hadoop driver! I read that, for running map-reduce using the driver, the inputstream can be set as Mongo database or mongodump files?

Comment: If the processing logic is not very complex then why not rewrite the Hadoop MR code to fit MongoDB's MR framework.

Comment: As the question asks for a 'better' way I don't think it can currently be answered objectively. As such I voted to close this question.